# RubyOnRails : read parameter from the database once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

How does this happen in RubyOnRails:
The parameter is stored in the database.
The program needs to **read it from the database once upon user login** and save them in a global variable.
While the user is working, he uses only this variable, and the program does not read parameter again from the DB, only the next time the user logs on to the system.
How it is implemented.
(edited) 
What if there is a **solution without sessions**?
**home_controller** : is only one time run in start of user session ?

Comment: Why are you storing this parameter in a global variable? What's the use case?

Comment: Why not just save the user session and generate the necessary queries?

Comment: Values of parameters may changed . I don't want change it in program, but take from DB  once when user login.
What if there is a solution without sessions?

Comment: Karim Tarek: main Q. is read it from the database once;
It will use so in models, controls, helpers and views.

Comment: What should happen if there signs in another user? Use the same global variable? Use a different variable? What if the user does not log out once they are done? Still use the same variable when they return a couple of days later?

Comment: No matter  :) , I'll work with those variables. Q: how read once from DB without session-var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it in the session hash

```
class ApplicationController
  def my_variable
    session[:my_variable] ||= MyFile.find(1).my_variable
  end
end
```

The app will only need to retrieve it once, the first time a logged in user references the `my_variable` method. After that, it will use the retrieved value even if the database value is changed.